# Python: How to import asciidoc3

Tags: python, asciidoc

How can I convert an asciidoc to html using the asciidoc3 python package from within my python script? I'm not able to find a working example. The official docs are oriented mainly towards those who will use asciidoc3 as a command line tool, not for those who wish to do conversions in their python apps.

I'm finding that sometimes packages are refactored with significant improvements and old examples on the interwebs are not updated. Python examples frequently omit import statements for brevity, but for newer developers like me, the correct entry point is not obvious.

In my venv, I ran

```
pip install asciidoc3
```

Then I tried...

```
import io
from asciidoc3.asciidoc3api import AsciiDoc3API
infile = io.StringIO('Hello world')
outfile = io.StringIO()
asciidoc3_ = AsciiDoc3API()
asciidoc3_.options('--no-header-footer')
asciidoc3_.execute(infile, outfile, backend='html4')
print(outfile.getvalue())
```

and

```
import io
from asciidoc3 import asciidoc3api
asciidoc3_ = asciidoc3api.AsciiDoc3API()
infile = io.StringIO('Hello world')
asciidoc3_.execute(infile)
```

Pycharm doesn't have a problem with either import attempt when it does it's syntax check and everything looks right based on what I'm seeing in my venv's site-packages... "./venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asciidoc3/asciidoc3api.py" is there as expected. But both of my attempts raise "AttributeError: module 'asciidoc3' has no attribute 'execute'"

That's true. asciidoc3 doesn't have any such attribute. It's a method of class AsciiDoc3API defined in asciidoc3api.py. I assume the problem is my import statement?

Comment: It's odd that the error message refers to a _module_ object.  Presumably that is the error you would get if you mistakenly wrote `asciidoc3.execute()` instead of `asciidoc3_.execute()`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It wasn't the import statement. The error message was sending me down the wrong rabbit hole but I found this in the module's doc folder...

[NOTE]
.PyPI, venv (Windows or GNU/Linux and other POSIX OS)
Unfortunately, sometimes (not always - depends on your directory-layout, operating system etc.) AsciiDoc3 cannot find the 'asciidoc3' module when you installed via venv and/or PyPI. +

The solution:

```
from asciidoc3api import AsciiDoc3API
asciidoc3 = AsciiDoc3API('/full/path/to/asciidoc3.py')
```